# How to override the default has_many condition for a relation in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, relation

I would like to enter my own condition for a `has_many` relationship in my ActiveRecord model.
I want my condition to **override** the default condition.

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :notifs, :conditions => 
   proc { "(notifs.user_id = #{self.id} OR notifs.user_id = 0)" }
```

And it generates:

> Notif Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `notifs`.* FROM `notifs` WHERE
>   `notifs`.`user_id` = 1 AND ((notifs.user_id = 1 OR notifs.user_id =
>   0))

I don't want the default condition of active record (the first `WHERE notifs.user_id = 1` outside parens). I want only my own. How do I specify that ?

Answer (score 4):

For rails 4.1+ you can use [unscope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-unscope) inside the association scope.

```
class Post
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :posts, -> { unscope(:where).where(title: "hello") }
end

User.first.posts
# => SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."title" = $1  [["title", "hello"]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace `:conditions` with `:finder_sql`like so:

```
has_many :notifs, 
  :finder_sql => proc { "(notifs.user_id = #{self.id} OR notifs.user_id = 0)" }
```

More details in the documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many

Comment: `finder_sql` was removed from [4.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-1-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md).